# cypress selector on dom element attributes

Tags: javascript, dom, cypress

I have two svg elements on my site:

```
<svg data-icon="times" ... > ...</svg>
<svg data-icon="sync" ... > ...</svg>
```

I like to select on of them based on their attribute `data-icon`. Something like this:

```
cy.get('svg').filter(?)
```

I Didn't find anything on the docu in the `cy.get` and `cy.filter` section. I know I could solve this by assigning classes or id around the elements or use the `cy.each` function to get one element, but for my tests this is a common problem and I am looking for the most comfortable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the data attribute directly. Here's how the code would look like:

```
cy.get('[data-icon="times"]')
```

This would yield the element with a `data-icon` attribute of "times".

You could be even more specific by explicitly targeting only svg elements with that data attribute like so:

```
cy.get('svg[data-icon="times"]')
```

[Here's the section of the docs for more reading.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Find-5-elements-with-the-given-data-attribute)

Comment: The double quotes are not required around times