# Not able to use attribute selector in cypress

Tags: vue.js, cypress

My HTML fragment is:

```
<label class="email">
  Email
  <input data-test="email" type="text" v-model="curMember.email_address">
</label>
```

Then in my cypress test the following 'GET' does not work (using attribute selector):

```
cy.get('[data-test="email"]').should('have.value', 'a@test.com')
```

the above times out trying to find the element but the folowing does work (using a class selector)

```
cy.get('.email>input').should('have.value', 'a@test.com')
```

Can anyone tell me what my problem is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cypress selector on dom element attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856919/cypress-selector-on-dom-element-attributes)

Comment: Having the same problem, it should work, but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that cypress provides of getting value from NON-class
but take a look at this https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Selector

for the first example, you can only check the length

`cy.get('[data-test="email"]').should('have.length', '10')`