# Get a div that has a specific child img src

Tags: cypress

I have multiple divs with multiple imgs under them. I'd like to get the div with the correct img src. How can I do this? I tried this and it didn't work. It just compared the src with the first div and failed.

```
cy.get('.card').find('.info-section > .logo').should('have.attr', 'src', '/assets/icons/fruit.svg')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cypress selector on dom element attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856919/cypress-selector-on-dom-element-attributes)

Comment: it doesn't. I need to get a parent that has a specific img child, not the img per se.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70079002/go-back-to-parent-element-css-selector-in-cypress

Comment: worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the search order - target the child element with that specific attribute, then traverse to the card parent

```js
cy.get('[src="/assets/icons/fruit.svg"]')
  .parent('.card')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would greatly help your situation if you provided the DOM to see the multiple divs and imgs.

I'll be using the example DOM below.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="info-section">
        <img src="/assets/icons/vegetable.svg" />
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/assets/icons/fruit.svg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="info-section">
        <img src="/assets/icons/vegetable.svg" />
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/assets/icons/fruit.svg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get the `<img src="/assets/icons/fruit.svg" />` and test it has src, you will do the following:

```
cy.get('div.logo') // get div with class logo
  .find('img') // find img children
  .should('have.length', 1) // should only return 1 element
  .should('have.attr', 'src', '/assets/icons/fruit.svg') // should have src attr
```

Comment: `.children('img')` should be `.find('img')` - your comment is correct! See the [example](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/children#No-Args), children does not mean descendants.

Comment: Ops, hehe. Thanks for that good catch! For my specific example `.children()` would work but probably better to use `.find()`.